# Add floating point value to android resources/values

Tags: android, resources, floating-point

I'm trying to add a little space between lines to my TextViews using `android:lineSpacingMultiplier`
from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineSpacingMultiplier):

> Extra spacing between lines of text,
>   as a multiplier.
>
> Must be a floating point value, such
>   as "1.2".

As I'm using this in a few different TextViews I would like to add a global dimension/value to my resources, but I don't know which tag to use, if it even exists.
I have tried all [resource types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html) that make sense to me, but none of them works.

What I would like to have would be something like this:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="text_line_spacing">1.4</dimen>
</resources>
```

Edit: I'm aware of `android:lineSpacingExtra` (which needs a dimension with an appended unit), but I'd like to use `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` if possible.

Answer (score 578, accepted):

There is a solution:

```
<resources>
    <item name="text_line_spacing" format="float" type="dimen">1.0</item>
</resources>
```

In this way, your float number will be under @dimen. Notice that you can use other "format" and/or "type" modifiers, where format stands for:

Format = enclosing data type:

- float
- boolean
- fraction
- integer
- ...

and type stands for:

Type = resource type (referenced with R.XXXXX.name):

- color
- dimen
- string
- style
- etc...

To fetch resource from code, you should use this snippet:

```
TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
getResources().getValue(R.dimen.text_line_spacing, outValue, true);
float value = outValue.getFloat();
```

I know that this is confusing (you'd expect call like `getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_line_spacing)`), but Android `dimensions` have special treatment and pure "float" number is not valid dimension.

---

Additionally, there is small "hack" to put float number into dimension, but be **WARNED** that this is **really hack**, and you are risking chance to lose float range and precision.

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="text_line_spacing">2.025px</dimen>
</resources>
```

and from code, you can get that float by

```
float lineSpacing = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_line_spacing);
```

in this case, value of `lineSpacing` is `2.024993896484375`, and not `2.025` as you would expected.

Comment: I tried using this but get NotFoundException, "type #0x04 is not valid", when retrieving the value from code.

Comment: can you be more specific about problem? you've probably used wrong data type for format...

Comment: @rodkarom to retrieve floats from xml, use this XML: `<item type="string" format="float" name="my_float">0.5</item>` and this code to retrieve it: `float my_float = Float.parseFloat (getResources ().getString (R.string.my_float));`

Comment: Got the same error as @rodkarom when using type="dimen", changed to type="string" and used gregn3 suggestion to retrieve it. Thanks!

Comment: @gregn3 Couldn't that be done simply with the `<string>` tag?

Comment: how would I use this in XML? `@float/text_line_spacing` isn't working

Comment: +Supuhstar, replace @float/... with @dimen, for example @dimen/text_line_spacing

Comment: I think you should remove the hackish part, the sollution is just perfect as it is.

Comment: Interestingly, the "really hack" approach is exactly what Dianne Hackborn recommends in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/LcADl0tveAY/ovQAzP-fYoQJ).

Comment: You can also retrieve value in kotlin: `val value = TypedValue().also { context.resources.getValue(R.dimen.text_line_spacing, it, true) }.float`

Answer (score 94):

As described in this link http://droidista.blogspot.in/2012/04/adding-float-value-to-your-resources.html

Declare in dimen.xml

```
<item name="my_float_value" type="dimen" format="float">9.52</item>
```

Referencing from xml

```
@dimen/my_float_value
```

Referencing from java

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getResources().getValue(R.dimen.my_float_value, typedValue, true);
float myFloatValue = typedValue.getFloat();
```

Answer (score 51):

All the solutions suggest you to use the predefined float value through code.

But in case you are wondering how to reference the predefined float value in XML (for example layouts), then following is an example of what I did and it's working perfectly:

Define resource values as `type="integer"` but `format="float"`, for example:

```
<item name="windowWeightSum" type="integer" format="float">6.0</item>
<item name="windowNavPaneSum" type="integer" format="float">1.5</item>
<item name="windowContentPaneSum" type="integer" format="float">4.5</item>
```

And later use them in your layout using `@integer/name_of_resource`, for example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="@integer/windowWeightSum"                 // float 6.0
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/windowNavPaneSum"        // float 1.5
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- other views -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/windowContentPaneSum"    // float 4.5
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- other views -->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it enables me to change dynamically dimension values upon screen rotation without having to write code.

Comment: @Vyacheslav for drawables, you should use standard **dimensions**

Comment: it doesnt work at all. AndroidStudio fails even with dimentions

Comment: I meant using `<dimen>`

Comment: What if we have to reference these values programmatically?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky did you find any solution for set the value programmatically?

Answer (score 29):

Add a float to dimens.xml:

`<item format="float" name="my_dimen" type="dimen">1.2</item>`

To reference from XML:

```
<EditText 
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="@dimen/my_dimen"
    ...
```

To read this value programmatically you can use [`ResourcesCompat.getFloat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html#getFloat(android.content.res.Resources,%20int)) from androidx.core

Gradle dependency:

`implementation("androidx.core:core:${version}")`

Usage:

```
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat;

...

float value = ResourcesCompat.getFloat(context.getResources(), R.dimen.my_dimen);
```

Answer (score 20):

I also found a workaround which seems to work fine with no warnings:

```
<resources>
    <item name="the_name" type="dimen">255%</item>
    <item name="another_name" type="dimen">15%</item>
</resources>
```

Then:

```
// theName = 2.55f
float theName = getResources().getFraction(R.dimen.the_name, 1, 1);
// anotherName = 0.15f
float anotherName = getResources().getFraction(R.dimen.another_name, 1, 1);
```

**Warning** : it only works when you use the dimen from Java code not from xml

Comment: This unfortunatelly doesn't work, if I use such value in XML definition: android:lineSpacingMultiplier="@dimen/TEXT_SPACING_MULTIPLIER". It causes NumberFormatException while inflating layout.

Comment: Exactly. It only works when you use the dimen from Java code.

Comment: This is the best way I could find to access floats from code.

Comment: In floats.xml I added <item name="shadow_percent" type="dimen">25%</item> and then in my drawable I used this percent to set the shadow gradient's center using android:centerY="@dimen/shadow_percent". This worked perfectly to set the shadow to 25% of the total height of the layer-list. THANK YOU!

Comment: just a note, you should use `type="fraction"` to avoid errors in Java code

Answer (score 9):

We can also use it for the guideline of the constraint layout.

Create integer.xml file and add into

```
 <item name="guideline_button_top" type="integer" format="float">0.60</item>
```

Use from a layout.xml file

```
 app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="@integer/guideline_button_top"
```

Comment: exactly what I need, I use this for different percent values for tablets and different for mobile without creating two layout files

Answer (score 5):

I used a style to solve this issue.  The official link is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Pretty useful stuff.  You make a file to hold your styles (like "styles.xml"), and define them inside it.  You then reference the styles in your layout (like "main.xml").

Here's a sample style that does what you want:

```
<style name="text_line_spacing">
   <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.4</item>
</style>
```

Let's say you want to alter a simple TextView with this.  In your layout file you'd type:

```
<TextView
   style="@style/summary_text"
   ...
   android:text="This sentence has 1.4 times more spacing than normal."
/>
```

Try it--this is essentially how all the built-in UI is done on the android.  And by using styles, you have the option to modify all sorts of other aspects of your Views as well.

Answer (score 3):

If somebody is interested in "tricking the system" when you are allowed to give only specific types of xml values, especially when using xml values for embedded weights in android layout formatting, you could do something like this:

```
    <item name="actvity_top_panel_weight" format="float" type="integer">1.5</item>
```

The xml value above acts like a float but is called an integer.

Then you could use it as the following without a problem:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/actvity_top_panel_weight"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No upwoted ? how can be :) , this seems to be only right answer here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have simple floats that you control the range of, you can also have an integer in the resources and divide by the number of decimal places you need straight in code.

So something like this

```
<integer name="strokeWidth">356</integer>
```

is used with 2 decimal places

```
this.strokeWidthFromResources = resources_.getInteger(R.integer.strokeWidth);    
circleOptions.strokeWidth((float) strokeWidthFromResources/ 100);
```

and that makes it **3.56f**

Not saying this is the most elegant solution but for simple projects, it's convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which works, but does result in a `Warning` (`WARN/Resources(268): Converting to float: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4d "1.2" a=2 r=0x7f06000a}`) in LogCat.

```
<resources>
    <string name="text_line_spacing">1.2</string>
</resources>

<android:lineSpacingMultiplier="@string/text_line_spacing"/>
```

Comment: see my answer above. you can use "generic" resource item, where you should specify format and type. format is for java type (float, boolean, fraction, integer, etc.), and type is for android gen resource reference ("dimen" for R.dimen, "color" for R.color, "string" for R.string, etc.)

Comment: This was my initial answer which is really outdated now, that's why I accepted your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although I've used the accepted answer in the past, it seems with the current Build Tools it is possible to do:

```
   <dimen name="listAvatarWidthPercent">0.19</dimen>
```

I'm using Build Tools major version 29.

Answer (score 0):

The float or double parameter can be stored as a string:

```
<resources>
    <string name="x">0.01</string>
</resources>
```

and then obtained as:

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(this.getString(R.string.x));
```

Use  java.lang.Float.parseFloat() if you want x parsed to a float.