# How does one use Resources.getFraction()?

Tags: android, android-resources

How do I store a fractional value like `3.1416` in resources? What to write in the XML and how to retrieve it in Java code?

The documentation for [`getFraction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getFraction%28int,%20int,%20int%29) states:

> `public float getFraction (int id, int base, int pbase)`
>
> Retrieve a fractional unit for a particular resource ID.
>
> **Parameters**
>   `base`    The base value of this fraction. In other words, a standard
>   fraction is multiplied by this value.
>   `pbase`   The parent base value of
>   this fraction. In other words, a parent fraction (nn%p) is multiplied
>   by this value.
>
> **Returns**
>   Attribute fractional value multiplied by the
>   appropriate base value

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6021880/165674) shows a simple example of percentages without going into the details of what the arguments mean.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You specify fractions in XML as so:

```
   <item name="fraction" type="fraction">5%</item>
   <item name="parent_fraction" type="fraction">2%p</item>
```

Where 5% would be 0.05 when actually used.

Then:

```
// 0.05f
getResources().getFraction(R.fraction.fraction, 1, 1);
// 0.02f
getResources().getFraction(R.fraction.parent_fraction, 1, 1);
// 0.10f
getResources().getFraction(R.fraction.fraction, 2, 1);
// 0.10f
getResources().getFraction(R.fraction.fraction, 2, 2);
// 0.04f
getResources().getFraction(R.fraction.parent_fraction, 1, 2);
// 0.04f
getResources().getFraction(R.fraction.parent_fraction, 2, 2);
```

As you can see, depending on the type of fraction, the `getFraction` method multiples the values accordingly.
If you specify a parent fraction (`%p`), it uses the second argument (`pbase`), ignoring the first.
On the other hand, specifying a normal fraction, only the `base` argument is used, multiplying the fraction by this.