# Is there a default place to save constants similar to string.xml?

Tags: android

Well the question speaks for itself. Should I declare an Enum or is there an already designated place within the app's file system?

Comment: SharedPreferences would be an extremely poor choice for declaring constants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a resource file in `res/values` with any filename you want, containing values of various types. [Read the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html).

Comment: Well thank you sir. Although I only see integers there, can you store floats and doubles?

Comment: Apparently you can. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282390/add-floating-point-value-to-android-resources-values

Comment: Tried the method shown in that thread but it doesn't work and I think the thread is dead :(.