# Resources$NotFoundException: resource ID not valid. Why?

Tags: android, android-resources

I am trying to add a float to my `dimens.xml` file.

I was reading the [following SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8780360/785215). When I tried the solution, I got the exception described in the comments. I am trying to figure out *why* that exception is thrown.

For completeness here is the XML:

```
<item name="zoom_level" format="float" type="dimen">15.0</item>
```

Here is the code that blows up:

```
final float zoom = this.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.zoom_level);
```

I jumped into the Android source, and here is the method definition for getDimension:

```
public float getDimension(int id) throws NotFoundException {
    synchronized (mTmpValue) {
        TypedValue value = mTmpValue;
        getValue(id, value, true);
        if (value.type == TypedValue.TYPE_DIMENSION) {
            return TypedValue.complexToDimension(value.data, mMetrics);
        }
        throw new NotFoundException(
                "Resource ID #0x" + Integer.toHexString(id) + " type #0x"
                + Integer.toHexString(value.type) + " is not valid");
    }
}
```

So for whatever reason `value.type != TypedValue.TYPE_DIMENSION`. I do not have my Android source completely set up so I cannot easily add a `Log.w("YARIAN", "value type is " + value.type)'` statement in there.

I then jumped into `getValue` and the chain of calls seems to be:

```
Resources.getValue -> AssetManager.getResourceValue -> AssetManager.loadResourceValue
```

`loadResourceValue` is a native method and here is where my digging falls apart.

Anybody know what the best way to understand what's going is?

---

I also noticed that `Resources` has a `TypedValue.TYPE_FLOAT` and `TypedValue.TYPE_DIMENSION`. But in XML, I cannot write `type="float"`.

The work around described in the comments is to use `type=string` and then use `Float.parse` to get the float. Is this necessary? Why or why not?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I know it's a late answer but you should use [TypedValue#getFloat()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#getFloat%28%29) instead of parsing the String to a float like you suggested.

XML:

```
    <item name="float_resource" format="float" type="raw">5.0</item>
```

Java:

```
TypedValue out = new TypedValue();
context.getResources().getValue(R.raw.float_resource, out, true);
float floatResource = out.getFloat();
```

You can put `fraction`, `raw` or `string` as the `type` if you prefer, this only corresponds to the resource class in `R`.

Comment: So where's this XML supposed to go? A dimen xml in res/raw?

Comment: @G_V Yep I think so - though I don't think it really matters as it all gets picked up by `R` anyway?

Comment: And do you know why I have to make this way? The default type is dimension, so when I use format="float" I make it wrong? Or that is something I should always use? thx in advance

Answer (score 4):

There's now [Resources.getFloat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getFloat(int)) (from API 29) and [ResourcesCompat.getFloat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/res/ResourcesCompat#getFloat(android.content.res.Resources,%2520int)):

```
val zoomLevel: Float = ResourcesCompat.getFloat(resources, R.dimen.zoom_level)
```

You can leave your `zoom_level` XML as it is in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem too, and though the error message isn't too helpful, I realized my problem was that I was putting just a float value in my resource file and didn't specify a measurement.  Switching 15.0 to 15.0dp for instance would avoid the problem and allow you to still use a regular dimension resource.

Comment: This only works if your float numbers are actually spaces. But in my case I have a `downPopLevel` which is a value between 0 and 1 for setting alpha on views. This solution is not correct in that case ...

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin extension function made from Rich answer:

```
fun Resources.getFloatValue(@DimenRes floatRes:Int):Float{
    val out = TypedValue()
    getValue(floatRes, out, true)
    return out.float
}
```

Usage:

```
resources.getFloatValue(R.dimen.my_float)
```