# Gradle , Unsupported type in xml

Tags: android, xml, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a xml file. dimens.xml. There I have an entry like

```
<item name="attr_name" format="float" type="vals">1.0</item>
```

However when I try to run gradle build, gradle gives an error 'Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'. Unsupported type 'vals'

I am fetching the value as `context.getResources().getValue(R.vals.store_list_view_width_ratio...`

How do I tackle this so that gradle does not give any error. Also I removed the type attribute, then gradle started saying unknown type 'item'

What should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**vals** is not valid. Use **type="dimen"** and **R.dimen...**
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20120240/2649012

Comment: Hey what happens if this value is declared in dimens.xml files of values, values-large & values-land-large folder. I am getting variable is already defined in R.java.

Comment: I should see the 3 values and the code. Normally you can have how many value folders you need. Make sure the same value isn't repeated inside the same file.