# Android resource of type long

Tags: java, android, integer

There is a type Integer in the Android resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="bytes_size">2147483647</integer>
</resources>
```

The maximum value is then 2147483647, so how could I have a bigger value in there, like a long? Do I have to put it as a String and then transform it to a long, or is there a better way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282390/add-floating-point-value-to-android-resources-values did you try this type of approach? It's float but see if it has long too?

Comment: It doesn't have a long type :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the ideal solution but you can store the value as a string and parse it during runtime.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="bytes_size">4294967296</string>
</resources>
```

Now you simply parse it into long.

```
String longString = getResources().getString(R.string.bytes_size);
long bytes_size = Long.parseLong(longString);
```

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I was trying to avoid to do. But as it's the only real solution for it, you are right.