# layout_weight in float and decimal

Tags: android, android-layout

I change the width of a view dynamically in my code using:

```
            final ImageButton ButtonTwo = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.callButton);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) ButtonTwo.getLayoutParams();
            params.weight = 1.3f;
            ButtonTwo.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The idea is that it matches another view in XML :

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@drawable/softkeyboard"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="softkeyboardButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1.3"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonstates"
     />
```

They're not the same width - the first button is wider than the second one. I know that this is because one is float and one is decimal, but how can I make them both the decimal size, or should I just do trial and error on the float value? My params.weight only accepts float values.

**EDIT:**
Here's my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView_2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>
<!--Let's set the height of the linearlayout below to 0dp. Apparently it's less work on resources,
as otherwise we would be drawing it twice, because the size is also set dynamically-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <!--android:adjustViewBounds="true"-->
    <!-- we want the text to begin in the centre of the edittext view
    that's what gravity does-->

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#d9d9d9"
        android:layout_weight="4"

        />


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/callButton"
            android:src="@drawable/call"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="softkeyboardButton"
            android:background="#ffa62b"
            android:layout_weight="2"

            />
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="#ffa500"
        android:text="New CheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        />


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:src="@drawable/softkeyboard"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="softkeyboardButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.3"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstates"
             />

        <View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="2px"
            android:background="#90909090"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:src="@drawable/settingsicon"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstates"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If the idea is to just have them match the `LayoutParams`, why not just retrieve the `LayoutParams` of the `ImageButton` indicated in the xml, then set it as the `LayoutParams` of the 'ImageButton` you want dynamically? Like so:
`buttonTwo.setLayoutParams(buttonOne.getLayoutParams());`

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Will look at it when home.

Comment: Let me know if it works, if it does, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: You can add it as an answer, for getting me round to that way of thinking. I was having terrible trouble with the float - params.weight = 1.3f. The widths were never exactly the same, even though I was using your setLayoutParams = getLayoutParams. Probably something to do with floats never being accurate, I don't know. But then I changed it to params.width= 80, and it was exact. You might add that part in ur answer, for clarification purposes to other users.

Comment: Posted it as an answer as you advised. But also just to ask, have you seen this particular [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8780360/4625829) where it mentions something different in retrieving float values?

Comment: Interesting answer alright. But in relation to my issue with your solution, 'width' is working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as answer as advised. :)

If the idea is to just have them match the `LayoutParams`, why not just retrieve the `LayoutParams` of the `ImageButton` indicated in the xml, then set it as the `LayoutParams` of the `ImageButton` you want dynamically? Like so:

`buttonTwo.setLayoutParams(buttonOne.getLayoutParams());`

And to quote @Christophe Harris for other users:

> I was having terrible trouble with the float - params.weight = 1.3f. The widths were never exactly the same, even though I was using your setLayoutParams = getLayoutParams. Probably something to do with floats never being accurate, I don't know. But then I changed it to params.width= 80, and it was exact.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `layout_width` to `"0dp"` for **ButtonTwo** for `layout_weight` to work correctly.

Hope this should work for you!